# Linux Pam creates static library instead of shared library

Tags: linux, gcc, android-ndk, autoconf, pam

I am trying to cross compile [Linux PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/) for android in the following way

```
`#!/bin/sh
# Linux-PAM/build.sh

INSTALL_DIR="`pwd`/out"

export
PATH="android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin:$PATH"
export CROSS_COMPILER="$PATH:android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin"
export SYS_ROOT="android/prebuilts/ndk/current/platforms/android-9/arch-arm" 
export CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
export LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
export AR="arm-linux-androideabi-ar"
export RANLIB="arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib"
export STRIP="arm-linux-androideabi-strip"

mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR
./configure --host=arm-eabi --build=x86_64 --enable-shared --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR LIBS="-lc -lgcc"

make
make install`
```

The output gives statically built libraries. I want shared libraries. If I compile for linux, it builds shared library by default. But for Android it builds statically. The config.log file has following

```
configure:3581: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=android/prebuilts/ndk/current/platforms/android-9/arch-arm -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=android/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-androideabi
Configured with: /tmp/android-8532/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.6/configure --prefix=/usr/local --target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/tmp/android-8532/obj/temp-install --with-mpfr=/tmp/android-8532/obj/temp-install --with-mpc=/tmp/android-8532/obj/temp-install --without-ppl --without-cloog --disable-libssp --enable-threads --disable-nls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libstdc__-v3 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-shared --disable-tls --disable-libitm --with-float=soft --with-fpu=vfp --with-arch=armv5te --enable-target-optspace --with-gcc-version=4.6 --with-binutils-version=2.21 --with-gmp-version=4.2.4 --with-mpfr-version=2.4.1 --with-gdb-version=7.3.x --with-arch=armv5te --with-sysroot=/tmp/android-8532/install/sysroot --with-prefix=/tmp/android-8532/install --with-gold-version=2.21 --enable-gold --program-transform-name='s&^&arm-linux-androideabi-&' --enable-gold=default


....

configure:10632: checking if libtool supports shared libraries
configure:10634: result: no
configure:10637: checking whether to build shared libraries
configure:10658: result: no
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems cross-compiling for Android from the command line. iOS is fun, too. See [How To Configure for Android?](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf/2013-10/msg00002.html) on the Autoconf mailing list.

I believe `host` is incorrect. Try:

```
./configure --build=`./config.guess` --host=arm ...
```

or

```
./configure --build=`./config.guess` --host=arm-linux-androideabi ...
```

If that's not it, can you post the full results from `config.log` (full relating to the shared object tests, not the whole file).

Sorry I can't help you further. I'm trying the cross-compile of Linux-PAM-1.1.8 on my MacBook (its set up for Android dev), but here's my result:

```
In file included from pam_modutil_private.h:14:0,
                 from pam_audit.c:12:
./include/security/pam_modutil.h:53:20: fatal error: shadow.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [pam_audit.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

$ pwd
/Users/jwalton/Linux-PAM-1.1.8
$ find . -iname shadow.h
$
```

Comment: Yes, i have corrected the compilation errors on my setup. shadow.h is not present in android. But till this step, automake and libtool has decided that it won't build shared libraries. This can be seen in config.log on your end also. I believe, the problem lies in configure and build script only.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this in the the big long log string:

```
Target: arm-linux-androideabi
Configured with: /tmp/android-8532/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.6/configure ...
--disable-shared ...
```

So shared libraries are disabled, which means you won't be building them.

Comment: Good catch. I had the same in my `config.log`. I guess this should be moved to the Linux-PAM folks so they can look into the issue. (Autotools is a mystery to me).

Comment: Yes, I observed that. But with the same build options i can build shared libraries for other packages. only libpam which uses automake and libtool is not creating shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I made small progress and found that the can_build_shared flag is turned off because it can not find dynamic linker for host type = eabi

configure:9299: checking dynamic linker characteristics

In configure script the check is as following

```
  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: checking dynamic linker characteristics" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking dynamic linker characteristics... " >&6; }


if test "$GCC" = yes; then
  case $host_os in
```

then there is a list of host_os like darwin, aix... but no swith case for "host_os=eabi"

This is the root cause. Looking for the solution..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by adding support for host type = eabi under the section for dynamic_linker and deplibs_check_method in the configure script.

Comment: Hi @Sunil, can you explain how exactly you fixed the issue ? After this, Have you cross compile PAM succesfully?

Comment: Made changes in libtool.m4 to add support for host type = eabi under the section for dynamic_linker                                                             `eabi)
        library_names_spec='${libname}${release}${shared_ext}$versuffix ${libname}${release}${shared_ext}$major $libname${shared_ext}'
      2490   soname_spec='${libname}${release}${shared_ext}$major'
      2491   shlibpath_var='$libdir'
      2492   shlibpath_overrides_runpath=no
      2493   dynamic_linker='eabi linker'
      2494   ;;`